# What does it mean to be born with a spirit instead of a soul?

Tags: religions-and-deities, spirits, glorantha, soul

[The HeroQuest write-up of the Kolat cult](http://brume.newgallo.dnsalias.net/pmwiki/uploads/Runequest/Cults/KolatHQ.pdf) says, of Kolatings:

> some  attract  dedicated  practitioners from those disaffected and dispossessed people born with spirits instead of  souls.

Does this mean that in Glorantha, some people run about with souls and others with spirits?  What difference does it make?

---

***Mod Note:* Answers are required to be based on Glorantha knowledge. General musings on souls/spirits or based on other settings/games aren't answers.**

Answer (score 7):

Here's as close the the official word as you're likely to get, and it doesn't really answer your question!

[From the Glorantha Lore Tumbler](http://glorantha.tumblr.com/post/97086371942/tell-us-of-ghosts-and-spirits-lawspeaker), as scholarly a site as exists:

> In Glorantha, everything has a spirit. There are spirits for
>   everything in nature; every tree, every stone, every animal, every
>   human and everything else. Your spirit is what animates you and gives
>   you life. It has many different names: your breath, your heat, your
>   shadow, your beast soul. Without your spirit, you are not alive.

it concludes with:

> Ghosts are a bit trickier to define. Like I said before, there are
>   spirits of the dead who are restless and dangerous to the living. But
>   there are also ancestor spirits, who are worshipped by many cultures
>   and are entirely benign. And there’s ghosts in the Underworld, where
>   dead spirits are meant to go. Either way they’re a type of spirit, but
>   it’s pretty situational, like many things in Glorantha.

And there you have Glorantha in a nutshell!